# php readfile not working with Google Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api, localhost

I was trying to make a php Script for downloads to consents form my Google Drive with this script for my website. I trying to use on local host and errors occur there failed to stream readfile error line number xx
Please help.

**The code:**

```
    $CLOUD      =   'http://googledrive.com/host/0B7vvcajRaUZhaThKdi1MNnAwVGc/';
    $fileREQ    =   '';
    if(isset($_GET['fname'])) {
    $fileREQ    =   $_GET['fname'];
    }

    $rand       =   rand(11, 99).$fileREQ.'.zip';
    $ORG        =   $CLOUD.$fileREQ;

//Below code for force to browser display save as dialogue box options;
header('Content-type: application/zip');

//Below code for rename the source file name to escape hot-linking;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$rand);

//Below code for Sending correct file size to be ready to Download;
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($CLOUD.$fileREQ));

//Below code for read original file from the source;
readfile($CLOUD.$fileREQ);
```

**The errors:**

```
Warning: readfile(googledrive.com/host/0B7vvcajRaUZhaThKdi1MNnAwVGc/Scanned Applications.zip) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\wamp\www\$$ avleen-php\GOOGLE_DRIVE\G-DRIVE.php on line 24

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for googledrive.com/host/0B7vvcajRaUZhaThKdi1MNnAwVGc/Scanned Applications.zip in C:\wamp\www\$$ avleen-php\GOOGLE_DRIVE\G-DRIVE.php on line 21
```

Comment: When does this error occur? What is the exact error?

Comment: Warning: readfile(http://googledrive.com/host/0B7vvcajRaUZhaThKdi1MNnAwVGc/Scanned Applications.zip) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\wamp\www\$$ avleen-php\GOOGLE_DRIVE\G-DRIVE.php on line 24

Comment: and--------- Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://googledrive.com/host/0B7vvcajRaUZhaThKdi1MNnAwVGc/Scanned Applications.zip in C:\wamp\www\$$ avleen-php\GOOGLE_DRIVE\G-DRIVE.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

You need the Google Drive API to do that.
See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Files for more information about the API